# Angular reactive form save values of datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I have a dynamic control with a datepicker. How do I save the values of the datepicker?

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td style="padding-right: 20px">{{item.id}}</td>
    <td style="padding-right: 20px">
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="estDate1" placeholder="Choose a date" [value]="item.estimatedDate">
            <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="estDate1" [value]="item.estimatedDate"></button>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-datepicker #estDate1></md-datepicker>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is my mock component implementation:

```
getData() {
        this.itemsForm = this.fb.array([this.item]);

        this.items = [{ 'id': '1',  'estimatedDate': '01/01/2017'},
            { 'id': '2',  'estimatedDate': '02/01/2017'},
            { 'id': '3',  'estimatedDate': '03/01/2017'},
            { 'id': '4',  'estimatedDate': '04/01/2017'}     
        ];
    }

    saveData(){
        this.itemsForm.setValue({
            ....
        });

    }
```

I am not sure how to dymanically gather the data from the datepickers and bind it to an array to pass to the service.

Comment: What do you mean here? Your `[value]` on your datepicker input should be updating your `items` array in real time when you change the input. That's what Angular data binding does.

Comment: You should put some identifiers on every data Input field and then read the identifier to determinant from which data Input field is the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to two-way bind with `item.estimatedDate`, you should use `[(ngModel)]`.

```
<input mdInput placeholder="Choose a date" 
  [mdDatepicker]="estDate1"
  [(ngModel)]="item.estimatedDate">
```

See [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/H5VsBmQonCx85jBJcAPq?p=preview) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the id for the datepicker dynamic. You can do this by setting the id of the element with a directive.

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="i+'Datepicker'" placeholder="Date of Birth" formControlName="DOB">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="i+'Datepicker'"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker [id]="i+'Datepicker'"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
```

Make sure you are getting the index of the ngFor array like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
```